# putting three dots if TextSize is more in android

Tags: android, xml

In Android, how could I limit the width of the TextView by **putting three dots** at the end of the text if the length is greater to certain limit ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put this code to your TextView

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"   // if you want 3 dots for single line, add this.
android:maxLines="2" // if you want 3 dots after two lines, add this.
```

Comment: was adding comments for explanation for each code. sorry it took some time.

Comment: but how does `maxLines` affects the display of three dots at the end?

Comment: if he has a text of 4 lines, but he wants to show the dots after 2 lines and doesn't want to show the rest of the text, this code is needed.

Comment: wanted to write this information in case if he or someone will need it as well? what is the problem with this additional information?

Comment: @MocialovBoris `android:layout_width="20px"` did he say about 20px width of TextView?

Comment: @PankajKumar he said about `limit the width of the TextView`

Comment: Why did you started a non-sense debate here... just chill both of u

Comment: @MocialovBoris but where is 20px? similarly why you are debating with him... :)

Comment: @PankajKumar Thanks, I just gave additional information in my answer for helping and had to explain this obvious thing to MocialovBori. Interesting that this became an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ellipsize property for this purpose.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_mytext"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

The code similar to the above should work for you. Also set `maxLines=1`.